# Socket.io for keeping data up to date in intervals every 10-1000ms?

Tags: javascript, mysql, socket.io

I am currently working on a project to display some data from my database in googlecharts. I want the provided data to be up to date when the data changes in at the database. For this i am using socket.io. But the problem i ran into was, to have one socket connection for all charts, but every chart has it's own sql query so i do a for loop of all ids of the charts to create socket.io events for every chart. (The chart amount is variable, so i cant set up fixed events for every chart)

It's my first project using socket.io but i'm not sure, if it's te right use case for this? My second problem now with this is, when reloading the page because some useStates updated, the data provision every time reloading gets slower (nearly doubleing the refresh time).

The code for initializing the events looks something like this:

```js
socket.on("init", async (ids, cb) => {
    const data: any[] = []
    console.log(socket.eventNames())
    if (!con) {
        con = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: "somehost",
            user: "user",
            password: "pwd",
            database: "db",
            connectTimeout: 3000
        })
    }

    for (const id of ids) {
        console.log("Initializing", id);
        socket.on("get-data" + id, async (payload) => {
            const { query, interval, _id } = payload

                intervals.push(setInterval(async () => {
                    const loadedData = await loadData(query)
                    if (loadedData) {
                        socket.emit("data" + _id, loadedData);
                    }
                }, interval))
            }
        })
    }

})
```

i am saving the created intervals in an array to clear them on disconnect.

Maybe someone can tell me if this is a right usecase for socket.io or if i should use some other stuff to do that.

Because i don't know the problem i just tried to clear some stuff like the events after running them but it didn't solve the problem.

I just thought if every time i run through this for loop something new is getting created again and again and so causing the system to get slower on every reload.

Comment: If you want the client to always have the most recent data, you should emit the data to the client when the data changes. If that's not an option, then you should use polling. The simplest way is to have one main interval in the server that's calling the SQL queries and emitting the data to all clients that have requested those ids. Imagine if 10 clients connected and all wanted ID number 1. Then you would end up with 10 intervals all calling the same SQL query over and over and this would overload your SQL server very quickly. Do one "main" polling loop (interval) and then just broadcast the

Comment: data to the clients that want that data. Or if it's not too large, just broadcast all the data to all the clients and have the clients filter it.